# View-targeted action propagating to sibling views

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to implement a basic table, with two rows for each player object. One is the edit row, filled with text fields, the other is the view row.

In my main template I'm using a CollectionView to render out the set of rows (players is a collection)

```
<table>
  {{view Ember.CollectionView contentBinding="players" itemViewClass="App.PlayerView"}}
</table>
```

I then defined a custom view to receive the click action:

```
App.PlayerView = Ember.View.extend({
 templateName: 'rosters/player_view',
 isShowVisible: true,
 actions: {
   toggleVisibility: function(){
     this.toggleProperty('isShowVisible');
   }
  }
});
```

Finally, I created the template for the view:

```
{{#if view.isShowVisible}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{view.content.name}}</td>
    <td><a {{action "toggleVisibility" target="view"}}>Edit</a></td>
  </tr>
{{else}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{input type="text" value=view.content.name}}</td>
    <td><a {{action "toggleVisibility" target="view"}}>Done</a></td>
{{/if}}
```

What I'd like to happen is that when I press the "Edit" link, it hides the text row, and shows the input row. What's happening is that it works fine if I press the first link, but, say I press the 10th link down, it will hide the show rows of 1-10, and then only show the edit of 10. It's almost like the event is propagating to the sibling views from the collection, or their attributes are somehow linked?

I tried setting "bubble=false" on the action, but that didn't solve anything, neither did returning false from my action, or preventing propagation inside there. An alert statement inside the action indicates that it's only being called once (so, not once for each sibling view). I'm new to Ember, so I'm open to any suggestions over what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually because of missing closing tr tag in the else statement.  Although this is ultimately the issue, I think when metamorph rips out and adds the table rows the browser has issues, but that can easily be remedied by pulling the tr tags out of the if statement.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EXEnUZE/1/edit

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="rosters/player_view">
  <tr>  
    {{#if view.isShowVisible}}
      <td>{{view.content.color}}</td>
      <td><a {{action "toggleVisibility" target="view"}}>Edit</a></td>
    {{else}}
      <td>{{input type="text" value=view.content.color}}</td>
      <td><a {{action "toggleVisibility" target="view"}}>Done</a></td>
    {{/if}}
  </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: Whoops...it was actually because the TR's were inside the tag. The closing tag missing was just my edit for SO going wrong. I wish I had more than 15 karma to give you for that one, I would *not* have found that any time soon. Thanks a lot!