# Lost views in template when change record of a route

Tags: ember.js

In this example http://jsfiddle.net/felipehw/F9UbR/ you can see the problem.

When you switch between the 3 names (contacts) in the example, the views App.FieldText (used to show each contact information) is lost if the current contact have fields not used by the previous contact.

The view used to display an information conditionally if it exists is:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="fieldText">
   {{# if view.value}}
     <tr>
       <th> view.field {{}} </ th>
       <td> view.value {{}} </ td>
     </ tr>
   {{/ if}}
 </ script>
```

And the view is used in this point:

```
      {{view App.FieldText field="E-mail" valueBinding="email"}}
      {{view App.FieldText field="Área" valueBinding="area"}}
      {{view App.FieldText field="Departamento" valueBinding="dpto"}}
      {{view App.FieldText field="Empresa" valueBinding="empresa"}}
      {{view App.FieldText field="Notas" valueBinding="notas"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a problem with tables in handlebars.

Usually I've found it's significantly easier to solve the problem using divs.  (I know this isn't a good answer, but if you can avoid tables it tends to be easier).  I've been investigating the issue on and off for a bit, if I find a good answer I'll update you.

[View-targeted action propagating to sibling views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826723/view-targeted-action-propagating-to-sibling-views)

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ABoZOxA/1/edit

Comment: Thanks! Removing `<table>`s fix this boring behavior.
But the real problem is with Handlebars.
I'll wait some time to close this question ... if someone knows a sane way to resolve this.